# Overestimated Monte Carlo results in brightway

Tags: brightway

I am running a Montecarlo simulation on ecoinvent v 3.8 consequential system model and when randomly sampling the activity *market for waste paper, sorted' (kilogram, GLO, None)* I get very unrealistic and overestimated results.

```
myact = bw.Database('ecoinvent 3.8_conseq').get('aae12a8b0ba521d60af5341c75cc9d3c') # waste paper sorted
mymethod = ('IPCC 2013', 'climate change', 'GWP 100a')
lca = bw.LCA({myact : 1}, mymethod)
lca.lci()
lca.lcia()
lca.score
```

Returns a value of -2.768 kg CO2-eq while

```
mc = bw.MonteCarloLCA({myact: 1}, mymethod) 
mc_results = [next(mc) for x in range(20)]
```

Returns values with a median over 100 kg CO2-eq. Which not only seems absurd but also skews all results in when sampling any foreground or background activity downstream, i.e. having this activity as input (e.g. cellulose fibre production `'48506ab8ea444c5e826cc079ff0d4c11'`)

I have tried removing all uncertainties for the exchanges in the activity but the result did not change.

```
for exc in list(myact.exchanges()):
    exc['uncertainty type'] = 0
    exc['loc'], exc['scale'] = np.log(1), np.log(1)
    exc.save()
```

**My question is:** how can I figure out if this is an ecoinvent problem or a brightway problem and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An excellent question, not easy to answer, but you can find my workings here:

https://github.com/brightway-lca/brightway2/blob/master/notebooks/Investigating%20interesting%20Monte%20Carlo%20results.ipynb

As of `bw2analzyer` 0.11.4, the modified recurisive function is included in the library.

As it is long and now included in the Brightway docs, I don't think it makes sense to adopt and add to the SO format.

Here is [one approach to reduce](https://github.com/brightway-lca/brightway2/blob/master/notebooks/Fixing%20large%20uncertainty%20distributions.ipynb) these large uncertainty intervals.

Comment: I thank you very much for this. I am not sure how to solve the problem now though. Should I modify the background system to change the uncertainty distributions of the upstream processes (tissue paper)? Something like: ```for exc in list(<<<the tissue paper activity>>>.exchanges()): exc['uncertainty type'] = 0```, and then ```exc.save()``` The problem now is that I don't know how many of these cases are potentially present in the database and I have a hard time trusting the MC results using default uncertainties!

Comment: I confirm that removing the triangular uncertainty solved the issue: ```myact = bw.Database('ecoinvent 3.8_conseq').get('d31acf4564148f0ef483a140317caf37') #cellulose fibre production
for exc in list(myact.exchanges()):
    if exc['uncertainty type'] == 5:
        exc['uncertainty type'] = 0
        exc.save()```

Comment: This unrealistic distribution was fixed in the ecoinvent 3.9 release.