# LCA in brightway- Is mass balance maintained during a monte-carlo simulation?

Tags: montecarlo, brightway

I am running a monte-carlo analysis for a single ecoinvent cut-off process (cement production) in Activity browser/Brightway. 1) Is there a way to perform a mass balance check for each run? Or 2) is Brightway also performing a mass balance check in the background?

If all the uncertainties, per run, are modelled independently based on their pre-defined probability distributions, I can imagine that matrix-based LCA formulation including uncertainty can't maintain a mass balance (without any additional steps)? Is this correct?

I believe this also links to a recent question "Overestimated Monte Carlo results in Brightway" ([Overestimated Monte Carlo results in brightway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72807629/overestimated-monte-carlo-results-in-brightway)) and the Chemical imbalance blog post (https://chris.mutel.org/chemical-imbalance.html).

Answer (score 0):

An excellent question! No, mass (or other) balances are not preserved by any LCA software (at least that I know of), as the data formats do not give us information on correlated uncertainty or joint distributions.

Brightway 2.5 introduces ways to fix this problem through the use of uncertainty arrays instead of independent PDFs, and there is a publication about this under submission. You can get a sense of how this approach works [in Aleksandra Kim's repo](https://github.com/aleksandra-kim/akula/blob/main/dev/Linking%20combustion%20emissions.ipynb).

Comment: That's great, thanks for the quick response Chris. And thanks for also sharing the repo. It's extremely helpful to see the notebooks.